# How to represent this complex data structure with Go structs?

Tags: json, struct, go

So I decided to give Go another chance but got stuck. Most Go struct examples in documentation are very simple and I found the following JSON object notation that I don't know how to represent with Go structs:

```
{
    id: 1,
    version: "1.0",
    method: "someString",
    params: [
        {
            clientid: "string",
            nickname: "string",
            level: "string"
        },
        [{
            value: "string",
            "function": "string"
        }]
    ]
}
```

How would you, more experienced gophers, represent that somewhat strange data in Go? And how to initialize the nested elements of the resulting struct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would use a `json.RawMessage`  slice for the `params` property.. then hide them behind an `GetXXX` method that decodes it all nicely. Somewhat like this:

```
type Outer struct {
    Id      int               `json:"id"`
    Version string            `json:"version"`
    Method  string            `json:"method"`
    Params  []json.RawMessage `json:"params"`
}

type Client struct {
    ClientId string `json:"clientid"`
    Nickname string `json:"nickname"`
    Level    string `json:"level"`
}

....

obj := Outer{}

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(js), &obj)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

fmt.Println(obj.Method) // prints "someString"

client := Client{}

err = json.Unmarshal(obj.Params[0], &client)

fmt.Println(client.Nickname) // prints "string"
```

Working (quickly smashed together at lunch time) sample: http://play.golang.org/p/Gp7UKj6pRK

That second `param` will need some input from you .. but you're basically looking at decoding it to a slice of whatever type you create to represent it.

Comment: Coming from a from a Python|PHP|JS|Lua background this looks like a lot of code just to do a very simple thing. Somebody really needs to fix Go xD Anyway, I like your answer: it's much better than what I did. Thank you.

Comment: Its only a lot of code because the JSON object is so strange. An array where one item is an object ... but the other item is itself an array? I can't see that happening in most system designs. If you have this in your system.. I do not envy you at all.

Comment: Not my fault. I'm working on an app to integrate a few electronic devices in my house and some devices have weird APIs, some of them are even worse with their SOAP embedded servers. Anyway, with Python, PHP, Javascript or Lua it's pretty easy to map this data structure. With Go it was surprisingly non straight forward, which is strange because almost everything I tried to do with Go has been easy as pie.

Comment: Your other options is to map it directly to a `map[string]interface{}` and navigate it manually in its entirety ... but thats much more work than the above.

Comment: But I was not criticizing your answer, you nailed it pretty well, it looks much better than the code I had. I just got the impression that Go could benefit from a more pervasive data structure like what we have with JSON objects, PHP arrays, Lua tables, etc.

Comment: Oh no worries - I never thought you were criticizing. Glad I could help :)